# How do I get the file to be sent from the request body as a parameter?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongodb

An example of the post request method I wrote with node js is as follows. I get the parameters like title, subject, message, email address, name from the request body, but how can I get the file to be sent from the request body as a parameter?

***Multer part of my API***

```
const multer = require('multer');


const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './tosign');
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null , file.originalname);
    }
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });
```

***Express js post request:***

```
 router.post('/sign',(req,res)=>{


    res.send('Sign request is called');

    var title = req.title;
    var subject = req.subject;
    var message = req.message;
    var email_address = req.email_address;
    var name = req.name;
    var file = req.files.file;


    const opts = {
        test_mode: 1,
        title: title,
        subject: subject,
        message: message,
        signers: [
            {
                email_address: email_address,
                name: name
            }
        ],

        //TODO - files from post request
        files: ['file.pdf']

    };

    hellosign.signatureRequest.send(opts).then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use multer which is a nodejs middleware to handle file uploading, there are many options available but I think multer is the most reliable option. You can find about it in the below mentioned link:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

After integrating it, you will be able to get files in req.files

Try below mentioned code:

```
const multer = require('multer');

const upload = multer({ dest: "src/uploads" });

// In case of file array
const uploadConfig = upload.array("profilePic", 12); 

// In case of single file you can use
const uploadConfig = upload.single("profilePic"); 

router.use(uploadConfig);

router.post('/sign',(req,res)=>{
   // req.file if you have used upload.single 
   // req.files if you have used array
   console.log('req', req.file);
}
```

Comment: ı added my code and also added my question can you check again?

Comment: @okoreni,
I have edited my answer , hope this will help you.